# Fast way to find locally maximal gradient values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a 2-d array for which I want to detect all locally maximal array indices. That is, given an index (i, j), its maximum gradient is the largest absolute change from any of its 8 neighboring values:

```
Index: (i, j)

Neighbors:
(i-1,j+1)  (i,j+1)  (i+1,j+1)
(i-1,j)    [index]    (i+1,j)
(i-1,j-1)  (i,j-1)  (i+1,j-1)

Neighbor angles:
315           0            45
270        [index]         90
225          180          135

MaxGradient(i,j) = Max(|Val(index) - Val(neighbor)|)
```

The index is said to be *locally maximal* if its MaxGradient is at least as large as any of its neighbors' own MaxGradients.

The output of the algorithm should be a 2-d array of tuples, or a 3-d array, where for each index in the original array, the output array contains a value indicating if that index was locally maximal and, if so, the angle of the gradient.

My initial implementation simply passed over the array twice, once to calculate the max gradients (stored in a temporary array) and then once over the temp array to determine the locally maximal indices. Each time, I did this via for loops, looking at each index individually.

Is there some more efficient way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Gradient is a misnomer in this case isn't it? You are really computing differences, if you wanted the gradient, the calculation for the "diagonal" neighbours must be different to the "row and column" neighbours

Comment: That's a good point. I suppose it's possible that I misunderstood the algorithm. This is the second half of the edge detection algorithm from the AIMA (third edition) book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cyborg pointed out, there are only four differences which need to be computed to complete your calculation (note that there really should be a factor of 1/sqrt(2) for the diagonal and antidiagonal calculations if this really is a spatial gradient calculation on a uniform grid). If I have understood your question, the implementation with numpy could be something like this:

```
A=np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10)

# Padded copy of A
B=np.empty((12,12))
B[1:-1,1:-1]=A
B[0,1:-1]=A[0,:]   
B[-1,1:-1]=A[-1,:]
B[1:-1,0]=A[:,0]
B[1:-1,-1]=A[:,-1]
B[0,0]=A[1,1]
B[-1,-1]=A[-1,-1]
B[-1,0]=A[-1,0]
B[0,1]=A[0,1]

# Compute 4 absolute differences
D1=np.abs(B[1:,1:-1]-B[:-1,1:-1]) # first dimension
D2=np.abs(B[1:-1,1:]-B[1:-1,:-1]) # second dimension
D3=np.abs(B[1:,1:]-B[:-1,:-1]) # Diagonal
D4=np.abs(B[1:,:-1]-B[:-1,1:]) # Antidiagonal

# Compute maxima in each direction
M1=np.maximum(D1[1:,:],D1[:-1,:])
M2=np.maximum(D2[:,1:],D2[:,:-1])
M3=np.maximum(D3[1:,1:],D3[:-1,:-1])
M4=np.maximum(D4[1:,:-1],D4[:-1,1:])

# Compute local maximum for each entry
M=np.max(np.dstack([M1,M2,M3,M4]),axis=2)
```

That will leave your with the maximum difference in each of the 4 directions of the input A in M. A similar idea can be used for labelling the locally maximal values, culminating in something like

```
T=np.where((M==np.max(np.dstack([Ma,Mb,Mc,Md,Me,Mf,Mg,Mh]),axis=2)))
```

which would give you an array contained the coordinates of locally maximal values in M

Comment: The padded copy of A can be simply calculated by doing `B = np.pad(A, 1, mode='edge')`. No idea if this option was available in numpy at the time of the answer (now more than 12 years ago).

Answer (score 2):

Consider these 8 relative indexes:

```
X1 X2 X3
X4 X  X5
X6 X7 X8
```

You can compute for every pixel X the differences `D1=Val(X)-Val(X1)`, `D2=Val(X)-Val(X2)`, `D3=Val(X)-Val(X3)`, `D4=Val(X)-Val(X4)`. You don't need to compute the other differences because they are mirrors of the first four.
To compute the differences, you can pad the image with a row and a column of zeros and subtract.

Comment: Wouldn't that just calculate X1-X?

Comment: @Wesley, to calculate X-X2, pad a row instead of a column and a row.

Comment: So I basically will create 8 arrays (4 padded + 4 result arrays) and then is there some fast way to take the max over each of the four result arrays?

Comment: Don't loop, just use `numpy.maximum`. You can concatenate the arrays in a new dimension.